# pass text to facebook wall on a button click android

Tags: android, facebook

I have to publish some text and image from a  button on the xml layout, onclick of the button it will call an activity to share but how to pass text and images to face book through android.
please help me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

probably through the [facebook-api](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

Comment: i have integrated the api but want to pass text from one activity to facebook

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code for Adding Image and Title in Facebook Post Wall :

```
  String link ="www.google.com";
  String image_url="http://dev.campusflock.com/img/medium_big_thumb/Deal/15.d23a69cbfb987be82dbfa563258080b9.jpg";
  parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
                    
        parameters.putString(
        "attachment",
        "{\"name\":\""
            + "companyName"
        + "\",\"href\":\""
            + link
        + "\",\"description\":\""
        + "Title"
        + "\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\""+image_url+"\",\"href\":\"" +link+"\"}]}");
    
        authenticatedFacebook.dialog(Main.this, "stream.publish",parameters, new TestUiServerListener());
```

Comment: i am doing like this  String shareText = "You Scored"+counter+"Out of 12 on Quiz";
   
  Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShareIt.class);
  myintent.putExtra("ShareText", shareText);
  myintent.putExtra("ImageUrl", CommonKeys.FbQuizImageUrl);  
  startActivity(myintent);